# How do I use a stored proc output parameter in reportbuilder 3

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that I am building in ReportBuilder 3.0 and it uses a sproc as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Qma].[UspGetCompareAsSold] 
    @ProjectNumber  AS NVARCHAR(50), 
    @Message    AS NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

I need to be able to report back any messages (@Message) on the report, these usually being error messages etc...

However I have been unable to find a way to do this.  The report works great with the sproc, but when I put in an invalid project number I need to report back on the report that the project was invalid and the @message returned will have information related to the logic within that the user will need to know.

I have tried the following in the expression field:

```
=Parameters!Message.Value
```

but that does not work.  Is there anyway to display the contents of my output parameter @Message?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create another stored procedure that returns all of the fields from the first procedure as well as the output parameter value as a new field.

This article from Alex Whittles is a great example of how to do this: [use-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-ssrs](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2008/08/use-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-ssrs/)

Alex notes:

> These values are repeated for every record returned, but all you have to do is take the value from the first record =First(Fields!Output.Value).